# Dynamodb ExpressionAttributeValues with List of Object

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Dynamodb table called "Users" and there are basic user information and their contact. The data structure as below:

```
{
  "ContactList": [
    {
      "ContactNumber": "+123 123456789",
      "ContactWayCode": "PHONE"
    },
    {
      "ContactNumber": "+123 123456789",
      "ContactWayCode": "WHATSAPP"
    }
  ],
  "Email": "abc@gmail.com",
  "Id": "ff94beab-7d4c-4231-b948-84257596d33b",
  "Name": "Tester",
  "Password": "xxxxxxxx",
}
```

I would like to update the Name and the contact list by updateItem function.
So I created a List of Attribute value for contacts first:

```
foreach (var contact in user.ContactList)
{
    Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> contactAttributeValue = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>();
    AttributeValue attribute = new AttributeValue();
    attribute.S = contact.ContactWayCode;
    contactAttributeValue.Add(nameof(contact.ContactWayCode), attribute);

    attribute.S = contact.ContactNumber;
    contactAttributeValue.Add(nameof(contact.ContactNumber), attribute);

    attributeValueList.Add(attribute);
}
```

And I put the List of Attribute value into ExpressionAttributeValues section with request:

```
var request = new UpdateItemRequest
{
    .......

    ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>()
    {
        { ":" + nameof(user.Name), new AttributeValue { S = StringHelper.sstr(user.Name) }},
        { ":" + nameof(user.ContactList), new AttributeValue { L = attributeValueList }}
    }
    ......
}
client.UpdateItem(request);
```

However when I call UpdateItem(request), I got the error message below:

> ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid value: Supplied
> AttributeValue has more than one datatypes set, must contain exactly
> one of the supported datatypes for key :ContactList"}

What should be the correct way to update the list of object in dynamodb? (Append if not exists, update if exists)